# Can I make a HTTPS hyperlink in Indesign exportable in PDF?

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf

Can I make a HTTPS hyperlink in Indesign exportable in PDF?
I tried to add the link through the hyperlink option page, but once I export it in PDF it doesn't recognize the link.

Answer (score 2):

When exporting a printing CMYK PDF, make sure the Hyperlinks option is checked:

[image]

**Test**

[image: test]

[image]

Comment: Yes, I know that but it doesnt work if it's a HTTPS link. I believe it only works for HTTP//

Comment: It works for me, I added a test at the answer. Are you sure you are putting the link at the right panel?

Comment: Doesn't work.... My link redirect to a video. I heard this is why it's maybe not working.

Comment: You are definitely doing something wrong, or the link is not right. Answer updated with link to video https.

Comment: Link is right because if I copy and paste it, it works.

Comment: its a mystery. I do it all the time but for some reason it doesnt work for this link.

Comment: Did you try other video links?

Answer (score 0):

I had no trouble with this - I set my PDF Export template to "interactive" and it had no trouble parsing an https secure socket layer URL.

InDesign - note that Hyperlinks palette is open and has accepted https input without issues.
[image]

PDF - note link highlighted under cursor.
[image]

Link clicked in Acrobat led to chrome opening the correct webpage without issue.
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: OK I think the link has something broken because I tried with any other https address that link to video and it works. I'll figure something with the video agency. Many thanks to all for your help.